# Local Notification Banners Don't Appear

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I am making an app which requires notifications to be sent to a user. So far, I have registered for notifications in the App Delegate:

```
let notifTypes: UIUserNotificationType = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
    let notifSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notifTypes, categories: nil)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notifSettings)
```

And call the following code to send the notifications in the View Controller:

```
 let localNotification: UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
 localNotification.alertAction = "Testing notifications on iOS8"
 localNotification.alertBody = "Here is a notification"
 localNotification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 5)
 localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
 UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
```

If I pull down the notification center panel, the notification is shown, but there is no banner if I am out of the app, and no notification shows on the lock screen if the phone is off. How can I get the notifications to show on the lock screen/as banners if I am outside of the app?

Comment: "no notification shows on the lock screen if the phone is off" If the phone is truly _off_ how can _anything_ appear on the lock screen?

Answer (score 1):

What you see, in the role of user, when a notification fires depends on your settings in preferences. You'd need to go to Settings and configure this app to display banners and to display notifications in the lock screen.

Also I would suggest that for purposes of testing you should schedule the notification at a bit later interval. You are saying `NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 5)` - that is not very much time to get yourself out of the app! The notification may be firing while you are still in the app — in which case no banner will appear.